# How to calculate years for a column of "Jan 1" formatted dates?

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, formatting

I have several columns of data, imported via `ImportXml` from a website, in which all dates are formatted like this:

| A | B | Year for A | Year for B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 22 | Feb 3 | `=Sequence(366-21, 1, 2020, 0)` | `=Sequence(366-31-2, 1, 2020, 0)` |
| Jan 23 | Feb 4 |  |  |
| *...one row* | *per day* | *in 2020...* |  |
| Dec 31 | ... |  |  |
| Jan 1 | ... | `=Sequence(365, 1, 2021, 0)` |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |

I need to convert these to real dates, so need a year (starting with 2020). I currently fill in the year columns via `Sequence`, which is hasslesome because I need to put in a custom formula for each column based on the start date, and I need to repeat the sequence for each new year.

Does somebody have a better idea?

Comment: share a copy (sample) of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text conversion to date is done like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:B="",,A2:B*1))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",, DATE(2020+IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(
 IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, A2:A, "=jan 1", 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))<>"", {ROW(A2:A), 
 IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, A2:A, "=jan 1", 
 ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))))}), 2, 1), 0), MONTH(A2:A*1), DAY(A2:A*1))))
```

[image]

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",, DATE(2020+IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B), IF(
 IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, A2:A, "=dec 31", 
 ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))))<>"", {ROW(B2:B), 
 IFERROR(1/(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, A2:A, "=dec 31", 
 ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))))}), 2, 1), 0), MONTH(B2:B*1), DAY(B2:B*1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Your sample is almost correct except that Jan 22 should be in 2020.
What I need is just a way to tell how many "2020"s I need to fill in based on the start date. (Btw converting a text to a date is usually done using `Datevalue`.)

Comment: is the A column always 2020 and B column 2021 ?

Comment: It changes from 2020 to 2021 when Jan 1 is encountered (and would change to 2022 when the second Jan 1 would be encountered, which will happen in about a year)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: The whole thing is extremely large, and I'm still fixing this "y2021" bug, but https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rUDt2ZWDvNveKYZJtLLw_UVZq1GW4ieEYBge-2_O6-M/copy . The part in question is `'WoM Raw' !Y:AB`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, quite some effort! I don't really get why in your column E it puts the year boundary after (the second) Feb 5. But anyway this sequence would not occur in the real data, we always have Dec 31..Jan 1, so I think your solution works.

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure it does. What happens on Feb 29? I think MONTH and DAY fail to parse this as a month/day if our current year is not a leap year.

Comment: Yup, for Feb 29 to work, I needed to use `MONTH((B2:B & ", 2020")*1)` etc.